# Dockerise Nginx, PHP-FPM using Sentry local server

Tags: php, nginx, docker, sentry

Currently I encountered a problem when using local Sentry server. I'm using Lumen 5.4 and sentry-laravel package to write logs to Sentry server. But I got failed

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n9ZwI.png)

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  ##
  # Autodiscovery : Consul
  ##
  autodiscovery:
    build: ./autodiscovery/
    mem_limit: 128m
    expose:
      - 53
      - 8300
      - 8301
      - 8302
      - 8400
      - 8500
    ports:
      - 8500:8500
    dns:
      - 127.0.0.1
  ##
  # Book Microservice
  ##
  microservice_book_fpm:
    build: ./microservices/book/php-fpm/
    volumes_from:
      - source_book
    links:
      - autodiscovery
      - microservice_book_database
    expose:
      - 8080
    environment:
      - BACKEND=microservice-book-nginx
      - CONSUL=autodiscovery

  microservice_book_nginx:
    build: ./microservices/book/nginx/
    volumes_from:
      - source_book
    links:
      - autodiscovery
      - microservice_book_fpm
    environment:
      - BACKEND=microservice-book-fpm
      - CONSUL=autodiscovery
    ports:
      - 8443:443
      - 8081:80
      - 9091:9090

  microservice_book_database:
    build: ./microservices/book/database/
    environment:
      - CONSUL=autodiscovery
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=bookr_pwd
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=bookr
      - MYSQL_USER=bookr_usr
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=bookr_pwd
    ports:
      - 6666:3306

  ##
  # Sentry
  ##
  sentry_redis:
    image: redis
    expose:
      - 6379

  sentry_postgres:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=sentry
      - POSTGRES_USER=sentry
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/data
    expose:
      - 5432

  sentry:
    image: sentry
    links:
      - sentry_redis
      - sentry_postgres
    ports:
      - 9876:9000
    environment:
      SENTRY_SECRET_KEY: 'b837e5a087c0a8727b1279bcdbe5a8a1'
      SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST: sentry_postgres
      SENTRY_REDIS_HOST: sentry_redis
      SENTRY_DB_USER: sentry
      SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD: sentry

  sentry_celery_beat:
    image: sentry
    links:
      - sentry_redis
      - sentry_postgres
    command: sentry run cron
    environment:
      SENTRY_SECRET_KEY: 'b837e5a087c0a8727b1279bcdbe5a8a1'
      SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST: sentry_postgres
      SENTRY_REDIS_HOST: sentry_redis
      SENTRY_DB_USER: sentry
      SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD: sentry

  sentry_celery_worker:
    image: sentry
    links:
      - sentry_redis
      - sentry_postgres
    command: sentry run worker
    environment:
      SENTRY_SECRET_KEY: 'b837e5a087c0a8727b1279bcdbe5a8a1'
      SENTRY_POSTGRES_HOST: sentry_postgres
      SENTRY_REDIS_HOST: sentry_redis
      SENTRY_DB_USER: sentry
      SENTRY_DB_PASSWORD: sentry

  ##
  # Telemetry: prometheus
  ##
  telemetry:
    build: ./telemetry/
    links:
      - autodiscovery
    expose:
      - 9090
    ports:
      - 9090:9090

  ##
  # Source containers
  ##
  source_book:
    image: nginx:stable
    volumes:
      - ../source/book:/var/www/html
    command: "true"
```

Please help me figure out why I couldn't connect to local Sentry server from Docker container. Many thanks and sorry for my bad English :(